# Unable to encode the unicode character during writing to a file in python

Tags: python, unicode

Here i am extracting the bible verses from locally stored html files using python actually this python is not written by me i got from somewhere, when i run the python code to extract the bible verses i am getting something like this type `u'Joseph asopo atum aphan Jakob thek-longsi, alangli arjulo, \u201cLahei komat asomarlo?\u201d'` it has many lines of such types, it is unable to encode properly the unicode character when it is going to write a file. While running on terminal it display correctly with properly encode the unicode character. Here is the python code if somebody can correct the problem, here is the locally stored html  [download html files in zip](https://archive.org/download/stack_201907/files.zip)  here is [Python file](https://archive.org/download/stack_201907/ReadBooksModifiedE.py). This python code is reading html files under folder `example` and generating output files inside folder `example/exampleoutputs`

```
import os, sys
import numpy as np
import array as arr
import re
from lxml import etree
from lxml import html
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import codecs
import shutil
class BIBLE_CLASS:

    def __init__(self,path):
        self.bookslist=[]

    def readBookList(self,path):    # Read the data from file
        file=open(path,'r')
        for x in file:
        #   print(x)
            self.bookslist.append(x)
        #print(Bookslist)
        #for i in range(1,len(self.bookslist)):
        #   print(self.bookslist[i])

    def searchBook(self,book):  # Search the book ID in the books file
        #bookcode=0
        for i in range(1,len(self.bookslist)):
            st=str(self.bookslist[i])
            #st=st.upper()
            #skey=book.upper()
            #print(st,'',skey)
            if(st.find(book)!=-1):
                temp=self.bookslist[i]
                index1=temp.index(',')
                #print(temp[0:index1])  
                bookcode=temp[0:index1]
                #print(bookcode)
                return bookcode

    def writeStoryFile(self,path):
        # Writes data into story file
        filext1=['.html']
        print("writeStoryFile")
        dirs=os.listdir(path)
            pattern=re.compile("^v")
        # CREATE A FOLDER WITH PATH+OUTPUTS AS NAME
        outputfile=path+"outputs"
        outpath=os.path.join(path,outputfile)
        if os.path.exists(outpath):
            shutil.rmtree(outpath)
        else:
            os.mkdir(outpath)
        for d in dirs:  #For each directory extract stories from files
            print("Directory name:",d)
            btitle=d[d.rindex('_')+1:]
            print(btitle)
            print('Book code:',o1.searchBook(btitle))   # Book code is extracted
            fullpath=os.path.join(path,d)
            if os.path.isdir(fullpath):
                print("Converting folder",fullpath)
                files=os.listdir(fullpath)
            rno=0
            # GET THE BOOK CODE FROM THE FILE
            btitle=d[d.rindex('_')+1:]   
            #print(btitle)  
            #print('Book code:',o1.searchBook(btitle))
            bcode=o1.searchBook(btitle)
            print(bcode)

            # CREATE STORY LINE FILE FOR EACH FOLDER
            csvfile1=outpath+"/"+d+"story.csv"  # story line filename
            f1 = codecs.open(csvfile1, encoding='utf-8',mode='w')   # Creating story lines file
            csvfile2=outpath+"/"+d+"storyverses.csv"    # story line with verses files
            csvfile3=outpath+"/"+d+"veses.csv"   # only verses      
            f2 = codecs.open(csvfile2, encoding='utf-8',mode='w')
            f3=codecs.open(csvfile3,  encoding='utf-8',mode='w')    
            for f in files:
                fname,fext=os.path.splitext(f)
                rows=[]

                if fext in filext1:
                    print("=================Processing the file",f,"========================")
                    # Process the file
                    print "Stories in the chapter:" 
        #           fullpath=os.path.join(path,file)
                    wpath=os.path.join(fullpath,f)
                    text=open(wpath,"r")
        #           csvfile1=wpath.replace('.html','story.csv') # story line filename
                        html_doc=text.read()    
                        soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser',from_encoding="utf-8")
                        h3s = soup.find_all('h3')
                        storyverses=[]
                        storytitles=[]  

                        for h3 in h3s:
                        next_element = h3.find_next()
                        print next_element.text

                        if next_element.find('sup') is None:
                        print("Element is null")
                        required_element=next_element.find_next()
                        if required_element is None:
                            required_element=next_element.next_element.find_next()
                        if required_element.find('sup') is None:
                            break
                        required_element= required_element.find_next('sup')

                        superscript_number = str(required_element.find_next('sup').text)                    
                     #   print bcode,fname,superscript_number,h3.text                           
                        print "========",superscript_number
                        if len(superscript_number)>2:
                            storyverses.append(int(superscript_number[0:1]))
                            sn=superscript_number[0:1]  
                            print sn
                            st=int(bcode),int(fname),int(superscript_number[0:1]), str(h3.text)
                        else:
                            storyverses.append(int(superscript_number))
                            st=int(bcode),int(fname),int(superscript_number), (h3.text).encode('utf-8')

                        storytitles.append(h3.text) 
                        print st    
                        rows.append(st)
                        rno=rno+1   
                        else:

                        superscript_number = str(next_element.find('sup').text)                 
                        if len(superscript_number)>2:
                            storyverses.append(int(superscript_number[0:1]))
                            sn=superscript_number[0:1]  
                            print sn
                            st=int(bcode),int(fname),int(superscript_number[0:1]), str(h3.text)
                        else:
                            storyverses.append(int(superscript_number))
                            st=int(bcode),int(fname),int(superscript_number), str(h3.text)

                        storytitles.append(h3.text) 
                        print st    
                        rows.append(st)
                        rno=rno+1
                        #print storytitles[0]   
                    # Write story lines into file 
                #   f1 = codecs.open(csvfile1, encoding='utf-8',mode='w')   # Creating story lines file
                    for row in rows:               
                        f1.write(str(row))
                        f1.write("\n")

                #   csvfile2=wpath.replace('.html','verse.csv') # story line files
                #       csvfile3=wpath.replace('.html','veses.csv')     
#                       f2=open(csvfile2,"w")
                    verses=[]   
                    verseno=1   
                 #      f2 = codecs.open(csvfile2, encoding='utf-8',mode='w')
                 #      f3=codecs.open(csvfile3,  encoding='utf-8',mode='w')    
                    #f2=codecs.open(csvfile2,mode='w')
                    #f3=codecs.open(csvfile3,mode='w')
                        print "======================================================================================"  
                        k=0 
                        for y in soup.findAll('span',class_=[pattern,"heading"]):
                        sups=y('sup')
                        for z in sups:
                            z.decompose()
                        if verseno in storyverses:
                            st1=str(rows[storyverses.index(verseno)])
                            k=k+1
                            f2.write(st1)
                            f2.write("\n")
                            verses.append(st1)
                            print bcode,fname, verseno,'"'+y.text+'"'
                            st=int(bcode),int(fname), verseno,y.text
                            f2.write(str(st))
                            f2.write("\n")
                            f3.write(str(st))
                            f3.write("\n")
                            verses.append(st)
        #       print st
                        else:
                            print bcode,fname, verseno,'"'+y.text+'"'   
                            st=int(bcode),int(fname),verseno,y.text
                            f2.write(str(st))
                            f2.write("\n")
                            f3.write(str(st))
                            f3.write("\n")
                            verses.append(st)
                        verseno+=1
                #   f1.close()
                #   f2.close()
                #   f3.close()
    def writeVerses(self):  
        print("writeVerses")
        # Writes verses into verse file

    def writebothVerse(self):
        print("writeStoryFile")
        # Writes verse with story in between

# Main program
bookspath="BookCode/books.csv"
path='example'   # Change this to the actual path of the input data

o1=BIBLE_CLASS(path)
# Step 1: Read the book list from the file
o1.readBookList(bookspath)

# Step 2: Create story files
o1.writeStoryFile(path)
filext1=['.html']
dirs=os.listdir(path)
```

Here is the screenshot of some output files
[image]

Comment: Try placing `PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF8` infront of your command to run the script and see if that helps.

Comment: I tried as `PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF8 python ReadBooksModifiedE.py` the output is still the same @Panki